# What is the difference between ConnectTimeout and ConnectionTimeout in spring web services

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpclient-4.x, connection-timeout

In my application I am not sure if I set all necessary timeouts in webServiceTemplate to timeout request because sometimes probe task just stacked which block my taskScheduler.

There are couple of timeouts in HttpComponentsMessageSender like:

```
    httpComponentsMessageSender.setConnectionTimeout(10);
    httpComponentsMessageSender.setReadTimeout(10);
```

and when you are creating sender from httpclient:

```
public HttpComponentsMessageSender(HttpClient httpClient) {
    Assert.notNull(httpClient, "httpClient must not be null");
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
}
```

you can set another timeout in RequestConfig:

```
RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(10)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(10).setSocketTimeout(10).build();

HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig).build()
```

so what is the difference between `setConnectTimeout` and `setConnectionTimeout` ? Which of these timeouts is the most important ?

Comment: IIRC, the `connectTimeout` governs the TCP/IP connect handshake, while `connectionTimeout` governs blocking timeouts (e.g. when reading from a connection).

Comment: and I need to set all these timeouts or there are some reasonable values in spring ? Now I just set setSocketTimeout

Answer (score 0):

From the documents i see the first two parameters the connection and socket timeouts – are the most important

From [HttpComponentsMessageSender](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/transport/http/HttpComponentsMessageSender.html) docs

**connectionTimeout**

- Sets the timeout until a connection is established, and connection timeout exception will be thrown if the connection is not established with remote host

**ReadTimeout**

- Set the socket read timeout for the underlying HttpClient. A value of 0 means never timeout.

From [Apache HttpClient](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-timeout) doc

**ConnectionTimeout**

- The time to establish the connection with the remote host

**SocketTimeout**

- The time waiting for data – after establishing the connection; maximum time of inactivity between two data packets

**ConnectionRequestTimeout**

- The time to wait for getting a connection from the connection manager/pool. (HttpClient maintains a connection pool to manage the connections. Similar to database connection pool)

Comment: thx but when I debug code I found that when I am creating my own httpClient it build InternalHttpClient which use last 3 timeouts and first 2 are ignored. When I use HttpComponentsMessageSender with defaultHttpClient then first 2 timeouts are used